# How to try close popup on click button after executing some code?

Tags: jquery-mobile

I am trying to make button which are gonna do something and close popup ( button is on popup, I am using jquery mobile)

```
<div class="ui-block-b">
      <a href="#popupDialog" data-rel="popup" data-position-to="window" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-transition="pop">Feedback</a>
</div>
<div data-role="popup" id="popupDialog"  data-theme="c">
      <div data-role="header" data-theme="a" class="ui-corner-top">
           <h1>Feedback</h1>
      </div>
      <div data-role="content" data-theme="d" class="ui-corner-bottom ui-content">
       <h3 class="ui-title">Thank you for your participation!</h3>
       <p>Some content</p>
       <a href="#" data-role="button" data-inline="true" data-rel="back" data-transition="flow" data-theme="b">Cancel</a>
       <input type="button" id="feedback_send" value="Send"  data-inline="true" data-theme="b">
     </div>
</div>
```

When I click button I would like to send data to server and close popup ( I connect send with function which sends data to server but I don't know how to close popup after), I tried to emulate cancel click but it doesn't close.

Answer (score 7):

Popup can be closed like this:

```
$( ".selector" ).popup( "close" );
```

But in your case you should use it like this:

```
setTimeout(function(){
    $( ".selector" ).popup( "close" );
},1);
```

setTimeout is needed because web-kit browser cant close popup without a slight delay.

Working example: http://jsfiddle.net/Gajotres/B6TgZ/

```
$(document).on('pagebeforeshow', '#index', function(){ 
    $(document).on('click', '#feedback_send', function(){ 
        setTimeout(function(){
            $( "#popupDialog" ).popup( "close" );
        },1);
    });    
});
```

Before you close popup do everything that needs to be done. There also another approach, you can always close your popup and trigger **`popupafterclose`** to do what ever needs to be done.

```
$( "#popupDialog" ).on( "popupafterclose", function( event, ui ) {
    // Do something here, it requires SOlution 1 to trigger popup close
    alert('Popup closed');
});
```

Of course this solution still requires button to trigger popup close function. But unlike solution 1 this will not cause slight delay (delay = action you will do before popup is closed) before popup is closed.

Answer (score 0):

It worked for me to place data-rel="back" in the button, as I was catching the click with another on click function. This way you get to call your function and close the popup.